# How to add a VBA macro to a list of standard functions in formula bar?

Tags: excel, vba

I have my own macro defined in the Sheet1, for example:

```
Function MyPower(rad As Double) As Double
Dim res As Double
If rad = 0 Then
  res = 0
Else
  res = 0.01 * Exp(1.7 * Log(rad))
Power = res
End If
End Function
```

I want to be able to invoke it via a formula bar like one of the standard functions, i.e. fx = MyPower("A1"), the same way as fx = Cos("A1"), for example.

What do I need to do to add this macro to a formula bar? I am sure it's very simple, but it does not work by default.

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Create your function in a Module instead of a Sheet macro.

You also mis-placed and mis-typed the return value...

```
Function MyPower(rad As Double) As Double
    Dim res As Double
    If rad = 0 Then
      res = 0
    Else
      res = 0.01 * Exp(1.7 * Log(rad))
    End If
    MyPower = res ' <-- "MyPower": Move it here
End Function
```

Comment: well just to make it clear because he probably thought it couldnt have the same name- , The return variable must have the same name as the UDF( User Defined Function)